# Determining the matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, and let $V$ denote the space of $n$-dimensional row vectors. What is the matrix of the linear operator ‘‘right multiplication by $A$’’ with respect to the standard basis of $V$?